# Multiple Linkedin accounts

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, linkedin-api

I required multiple accounts enable in my app. Social accounts (Facebook, Twitter and Linkedin). For facebook I am using switchusersample but unable to find the way that how to implement multiple concept for linkedin and twitter. If anyone has some idea please help me out. what should I do to acheive my requirements.

Thanks in advance.